# Body content overlaps with footer

Tags: html, css

i'm new here and i don't know much about css / html.

i need your help with the following problem:

my footer content is constantly overlapped by my body content.

i don't know what the reason could be. do i have to adjust something in my footer?

here is an example:

```js
function addFooter() {
  var pageStringPrefix = "Page ";
  var pageStringMiddle = " of ";
  var heightPerPage = 1000;
  var bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
  var totalPages = Math.ceil(bodyHeight / heightPerPage);
  var currentPage = 1;
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.style.display = "block";
  element.innerHTML = "<div style='width:124%;line-height:1.2; margin-top:100px; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; text-align:left'><span><strong>test</strong><br>test</span>" +
    "<br><div style='font-size:8pt; color:#000000; text-align:right'>" + "</div></div>"
  element.style.top = currentPage * heightPerPage + 60 * (currentPage - 1) - 35;
  element.style.position = "absolute";
  element.style.left = "20";

  for (var currentPage = 1; currentPage <= totalPages; currentPage++) {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.style.display = "block";
    element.innerHTML = "<div style='width:124%; margin-top:116px; font-size: 8pt;line-height:1.1; color: #ACACAC; text-align: center'><span> <br> <br> </span>" +
      "<br><div style='font-size:8pt; color:#000000; text-align:right'>" + pageStringPrefix + currentPage + pageStringMiddle + totalPages; + "</div></div>"
    element.style.top = currentPage * heightPerPage + 160 * (currentPage - 1) + 25;
    element.style.position = "absolute";
    element.style.left = "750";
  }
};

addFooter();
```

thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you sure is not an `html` problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What kind of page and what kind of footer is this? It looks like something used for PDF generation, but it's hard to tell. Do you want the footer to be once on the bottom of the website? Or do you want to simulate pages on your website somehow? It's very hard to help with just the information here :)

Comment: Also you should show your content; if it is just for example one extremely long image, what you are asking will be very, very hard. If it is a table or some paragraphs of text or such, you need to insert your "footers" into the actual data and not overlay them on top. The solution can be very complex depending.

Comment: hi joe! thanks for you answer! :-)
exactly, i use the code to generate a normal pdf. i would like to give the footer a fixed area at the bottom of the page and if the content from the body is too much, it should be written on the next page and not overlapping my footer.

Comment: is there a way, where i can send a private message in SO? i can send you the rest of the code, maybe this helps? :/

Comment: @kurtiburti, you can you post the html and/or css part too? You can do it by running the page and doing "right-click -> View page source" then paste the code between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags. It would also be good to include the css part.